# What is implication of ICMP timestamp responses?

Tags: vulnerability, incident-response

I have tried to understand CVE-1999-0524.
It is recommended to configure the firewall to prevent ICMP timestamp responses: https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-1999-0524
What if I will not do it?
What is implication of ICMP timestamp responses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ICMP timestamps are allowed an attacker can probe the network to find live hosts and potentially suggest trust between hosts (for example by constantly submitting traffic it would seem as the attacking node is in fact a regular in the network and trick pattern based IDS)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. How complex make the real attack?

Comment: not difficult with hping3: `sudo hping3 -C 17 1.2.3.4` Here is the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hping3)

Comment: But you should login to the server to perform attacks! Correct?

Comment: Nope, that's the point of the attack, you only check if the host is alive

Answer (score 0):

If ICMP timestamp responses are not blocked, attackers may be able to deduce the date and time on your systems. Knowledge of this can theoretically help attackers to guess numbers generated by weak, time-based random number generators whose unpredictability otherwise helps secure services.

Also it is possible to finger-print some operating systems more accurately based on how they respond to invalid ICMP timestamp requests.

The two points above are specific to ICMP timestamp responses. The other point already made above about being able to identify live systems applies to ICMP responses as a whole.

And by the way, disabling ICMP timestamp alone (Type 13 for request, Type 14 for reply) alone will not prevent an adversary from detecting live hosts. ICMP echo requests (Type 8) will still elicit a response from live systems. Solution would be to disable those requests or block them completely at a firewall with the possible side effect that troubleshooting network issues is more difficult.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now